# Google Cloud Endpoints - Do I have to use Extensible Service Proxy (ESP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webserver, google-cloud-endpoints

So, I've followed through the tutorial to get a basic end point working and it tells me I have to use ESP which is a Google thing based around Nginx.

Do I *have* to use this? What if I were to run my own web server/reverse proxy?

Would it work? I can't find anything anywhere about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take advantage of Endpoints API Management on GKE/GCE/GAE Flexible environment, the short answer is yes. For App Engine Standard, you can't use ESP and instead have to use the Endpoints Frameworks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I've worked out my issue anyway.